# WebBrowserControl in c#.net-Alternative Soution

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I am trying to automate web pages and want to submit a data entry form .
We can do with WebBrowser control perfectly but webbrowser control is a pain to get to work on a production server.
Is there any alternative solution instead of using webBrowser control?
How can I do programmatically this task. I can share you more details if need.

Comment: You can try http://awesomium.com/

Comment: Is awesomium.com free dll or i need to buy?

Answer (score -1):

[HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) would be helpful. You can make a GET or POST request. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/HttpWebRequest_Response.aspx) is a good example.

Comment: Junaid thanks you so much Attached are the screens ...can you see and guide me how i worn with HTTPWebRequest?